# What are the quality standards required to post here?

Tags: discussion

Sometimes, I get a "this message does not meet quality standards" validation error.

Where are the published quality standards for Stack Exchange sites?

Comment: As far as I know, you shouldn't be promoting anything, or being unhelpful or rude/aggressive... Apart from avoiding this, you should check out the [FAQs](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/faq)

Comment: I think I am on the right site, as I wish to post here, not on meta.stackoverflow :) Anyway I found a weak answer here http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92074/what-can-i-do-when-getting-it-does-not-meet-our-quality-standards

Answer (score 2):

The quality standards the error message is referring are not published, intentionally, to avoid users bypass the question quality system. The only guide about writing quality question is contained in two pages:

- [Why do I see a message that my question does not meet quality standards?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/quality-standards-error)
- [How do I ask a good question?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)